# R - remove as.numeric from string

Tags: r

I sometimes vectorise the variables I used in a model and do other stuff with it (e.g. descriptives etc...). The problem is that sometimes I use "as.numeric(var)" or "as.factor(var)", or center "I(var-15)". I then need the name of the original variables.

The problem is that I can't simply gsub(lmfit$model,"as.factor(","") because I get an error, and I want to avoid delete variables that contain I etc... so I need to delete I(* -any number) and  as.factor(*), where * is the variable name that I want to remain untouched.

Let's say I have a vector of coefficients from a model:

```
outcome <- c(1:9)
INDEX <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
BODYFAT <- c(18,18,15,20,20,20,15,20,15)
lmfit <- glm(outcome ~ as.factor(BODYFAT) + I(INDEX-15), family = gaussian())
names(lmfit$model)
```

How would you work on names(lmfit$model) to get the original variable names back (i.e. BODYFAT and INDEX?

I've started creating some clunky code to remove all the centering numbers (assuming 1 to 500 should be enough in most cases)

```
b<-paste(paste0("- ",1:500,"|",collapse=""),"-501",collapse="")
    library(stringr)
    str_replace_all(names(lmfit$model),b, " ")
```

But I'm having real problems with the removing I() and as.factor(). Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: maybe `all.vars(formula(model))` ?

Comment: Oh dear, it was that simple. Thank you Ben.